# Separate voltage regulators for different digital ICs

Tags: voltage-regulator, integrated-circuit, emc

I'm designing a board with an IC that deals with high-speed signals (HDMI and MIPI) and it also has camera (also MIPI) inputs. I was looking at the schematic of a board similar to the one I'm trying to design, and they used isolated voltage regulators for each IC, even for the same level voltage inputs. For example, they used one small 1.8v linear regulator for one IC, and then another small regulator for the camera core voltage, even though there's already a board 1.8v rail. Is this an EMI thing? Is it better to do this instead of using one larger 1.8v regulator for several ICs, which seems for efficient?

Comment: Please show an example for context. Isolated typically means galvanic isolation, which would mean it's a DC DC converter

Comment: This isn't really answerable without more detail.  Beware that many (most) devices don't permit I/O voltages to be present when power supplies are absent...

Answer (score 1):

High-speed chips have high-speed current draw. Thus, putting a long line between supply and consumer of current is an undesirable thing, because it introduces parasitic impedance. That's like you soldering an inductor in series with your supply!

Also, it's often way easier (and cheaper) to design a board with one (or maybe two) power rails going everywhere, often even on their own plane, and then convert down to lower voltage where that is needed,  than to distribute many different voltage rails with a low impedance.

> Is it better to do this instead of using one larger 1.8v regulator for several ICs, which seems for efficient?

There's nothing more efficient about having a single linear regulator instead of many. It might be cheaper in terms of costs of regulators, but again, you'll pay for that by massively complicated board design.

Answer (score 1):

There might be many reasons to do that.

It might simply be more convenient to do 1.8V locally for each chip, with a small linear regulator, than to have a single big regulator and route the global 1V8 plane around the board. As most chips need the voltages within 5% of the nominal voltage, it is extremely easy to have a 90mV voltage drop in copper traces, vias, and any possible filtering components such as ferrite beads.

The heat would also be spread around the board, instead of having a single hot spot.

Separate regulators may also be turned on and off when needed so if you only need the camera powers on, you can simply power only the camera without powering up the other chips.

A single 1V8 linear regulator could heat too much so it would have to be a switch mode regulator, which is more complex and more noisy, so it may be unsuitable for use as analog supply voltage for high speed tranceiver chips.

Also the chips may have different requirements for supply voltage sequencing at powerup or powerdown, so it can also be a requirement to have multiple separate regulators or some chips get supplies in the wrong order and get damaged either immediately or in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

> For example, they used one small 1.8v linear regulator for one IC, and then another small regulator for the camera core voltage, even though there's already a board 1.8v rail.

Presumably they wanted to keep the camera ADC from the switching noise on the other ICs. Usually a bad idea to feed ADCs noisy power.